# How to make the chrome browser window move down to show text continuously without user input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This page is for an art project; it should look like a ghost is typing continuously. More "real" text will be added and I need it to loop back at the end. The #1 problem is when the text hits bottom of page it continues, but can't be seen without user scrolling.
My cobbled together code is kind of working in chrome; however, I want the page to automatically move down when the copy continues to appear line by line at the bottom of the page, (without input from user). Also, I'm unable to break the lines with `<br>` or `<p>`. Tried using back tics instead of quotes and single quotes instead of double; line breaks don't work.

Below is the code I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
@font-face {
font-family: MyUnderwood;
src: url(~/typeWriter/MyUnderwood.ttf);
}

body {
font-family: MyUnderwood;
font-size: 30px;
margin: 10px 50px;
letter-spacing: 6px;  
font-weight: normal;

</style>



</head>
<body onload="typeWriter()"> 
<div id="testType"></div>

<script>

var i = 0;

var speed = 100;
    function typeWriter() {
    if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("testType").textContent += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
    
var txt = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed faucibus turpis in eu mi. Tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi. Elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit. Accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor. Lectus sit amet est placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed. In iaculis nunc sed augue lacus. Tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor at. Ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices. Fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque. Erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi. Vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam. Eget nullam non nisi est. A diam maecenas sed enim. Pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum. Nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis. Urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in. Ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit. Vitae sapien pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et. Purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est. Aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus. Venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor. Arcu odio ut sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet."

;   

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", typeWriter);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: P/s: Line breaks don't work because you are adding them as textContent and not as HTML.

Answer (score 3):

All you need is to force the scrolling parent (in this case it will be `document.documentElement` to scroll by its scrollable height. Technically speaking the scrollable height is `scrollHeight` - `offsetHeight`, but the [`scrollTo` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo) is smart enough that if you provide a value that is too large it will just scroll to the bottom of the element.

Then it is just a matter of calling `document.documentElement.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight)`. See proof-of-concept below (I have increased the speed by a factor of 10).

A usability warning tho: by constantly updating the scroll position can cause frustration to the user as it will overwrite whatever scroll position they are at: e.g. if a user scrolls up to read the earlier text they will be forcibly scrolled to the bottom every time a new character is inserted.

```js
let i = 0;
const speed = 10;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("testType").textContent += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
    document.documentElement.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);
  }
}

const txt = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed faucibus turpis in eu mi. Tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi. Elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit. Accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor. Lectus sit amet est placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed. In iaculis nunc sed augue lacus. Tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor at. Ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices. Fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque. Erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi. Vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam. Eget nullam non nisi est. A diam maecenas sed enim. Pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum. Nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis. Urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in. Ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit. Vitae sapien pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et. Purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est. Aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus. Venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor. Arcu odio ut sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet.";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", typeWriter);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 10px 50px;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div id="testType"></div>
```

### We can do better with `async/await`

There is actually no need to keep track of the index `i`, if we use a for...of loop. Moreover, if we use `async/await` we can make things a lot more readable without needing to worry about recursion, when used with a for loop:

```js
const speed = 10;

async function sleep(d) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, d));
}

const container = document.getElementById('testType');
async function typeWriter() {
  for (const character of txt) {
    container.textContent += character;
    document.documentElement.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);
    await sleep(speed);
  }
}

const txt = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed faucibus turpis in eu mi. Tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi. Elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit. Accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor. Lectus sit amet est placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed. In iaculis nunc sed augue lacus. Tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor at. Ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices. Fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque. Erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi. Vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam. Eget nullam non nisi est. A diam maecenas sed enim. Pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum. Nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis. Urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in. Ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit. Vitae sapien pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et. Purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est. Aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus. Venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor. Arcu odio ut sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet.";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", typeWriter);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 10px 50px;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div id="testType"></div>
```

### Want to use line-breaks?

If you want to introduce line breaks, I would suggest you split it up into an array of texts instead. The reason being that you still want to treat your string "as-is", but need to arbitrarily insert HTML `<br />` tags to create spacing.

You can store this info in any way you want, but let's say we run with an array of objects that basically store a string and an optional "breakAfter", which will insert `x` number of `<br />` tags as you see fit:

```js
const speed = 10;
const container = document.getElementById('testType');

async function sleep(d) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, d));
}

async function typeWriter() {
  for (const entry of texts) {
    // Assume we want to start a new line with every entry
    // When `entry.breakAfter` is undefined we fallback to 1
    // NOTE: This is ES6 object destructuring!
    const { text, breakAfter = 1 } = entry;
    
    for (const character of text) {
      container.innerHTML += character;
      await sleep(speed);
    }
    
    for (let j = 0; j < breakAfter ; j++) {
      container.innerHTML += '<br />';
      await sleep(speed);
    }
  }
}

const texts = [{
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
  },
  {
    text: "Foo",
    breakAfter: 3,
  },
  {
    text: "Bar",
    breakAfter: 5,
  }, {
    text: "End"
  }
];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", typeWriter);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 10px 50px;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div id="testType"></div>
```

Comment: code is doing what I want using "We can do better with async/await." now I'm moving on to try with, "Want to use line-breaks?" thank you Terry!